# Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `phone_number` on serializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

**AttributeError**:Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `phone_number` on serializer `ListBusCompanyStaffSerializer`.
Bascially I have two models `User` and `BusCompanyStaff`, `User` consists of phone_number field BusCompanyStaff consists of following models fields

```
class BusCompanyStaff(BaseModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        BusCompanyUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    position = models.ForeignKey(
        StaffPosition,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='position'
    )
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='created_by'
    )
    staff_of = models.ForeignKey(
        BusCompany,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

I basically wants to list particular BusCompanyStaff from BusCompany so here is my serializer I tried till now

```
class ListBusCompanyStaffSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    position = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = BusCompanyStaff
        fields = (
            'id',
            'phone_number',
            'position',
            'email',
        )
```

there is defintely Error as BusCompanyStaff dont consist of phone_number field but requirement is to put `User` phone number and email
Here is my rest of code in views.py and usecases.py

#usecases.py

```
class ListBusCompanyStaffUseCase(BaseUseCase):
    def __init__(self, bus_company: BusCompany):
        self._bus_company = bus_company
    def execute(self):
        self._factory()
        return self._bus_company_staffs

    def _factory(self):
        self._bus_company_staffs = BusCompanyStaff.objects.filter(staff_of=self._bus_company)
```

#views.py

```
class ListBusCompanyStaffView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = bus_company_user_serializers.ListBusCompanyStaffSerializer

    def get_bus_company(self):
        return GetBusCompanyUseCase(
            bus_company_id=self.kwargs.get('bus_company_id')
        ).execute()

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ListBusCompanyStaffUseCase(
            bus_company=self.get_bus_company()
        ).execute()
```

how can I serialize in this format

```
id  ,
phone_number    ,
position,
email,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
class ListBusCompanyStaffSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(source='user.phone_number')

    class Meta:
        model = BusCompanyStaff
        fields = (
            ...
            'phone_number',
        )
```

Comment: is there way i can pass in `extra_kwargs = {'phone_number':{'source':'?'}` ?

Comment: not sure, you can try to do the following

`extra_kwargs = {'phone_number':{'source': 'user.phone_number'}`

Comment: got this error when I tried in extra_kwargs `Field name `user.phone_number` is not valid for model `BusCompanyStaff`.
`